# Different link colors for citeauthor and cite commands

Tags: hyperref, color

This question is apparently the same as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384340/blue-color-for-cite-command-but-black-for-citeauthor-command#), where the author did not follow up by providing a working example.

I would like to make the color of `\citeauthor` links to be black and the color of `\cite` to be blue. In the example that follows, both the author and the number citation are colored blue, and there is apparently not a `citeauthorcolor` keyword for `hyperref`. How can I produce different colors?

> main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\cite{myref}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

> main.bib

```
@article{myref,
    title = {Fancy title},
    journal = {Journal of Fancy Publications},
    author = {Jane Dee and John Doe},
    year = {2017},
    pages = {293--311},
}
```

Compile: `pdflatex main; bibtex main; pdflatex main; pdflatex main;`

Comment: I would vote to close the other question as a duplicate of a non existed when asked :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a "hack":

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\let\oldciteauthor=\citeauthor
\def\citeauthor#1{\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}\oldciteauthor{#1}}
\let\oldcite=\cite
\def\cite#1{\hypersetup{citecolor=red}\oldcite{#1}}
\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@article{myref,
    title = {Fancy title},
    journal = {Journal of Fancy Publications},
    author = {Jane Dee and John Doe},
    year = {2017},
    pages = {293--311},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\cite{myref}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493075/173113) shows how it can be done with `citet` and `citep`, in combination with pre- and suffixes.