# Colouring citep/citet/citeauthor differently and based on environment

Tags: hyperref, color, environments, natbib, tcolorbox

I'm writing my thesis report in which citations inserted through `citep` en `citet` are blue, and the output of the `citeauthor`-command is the regular text color. I've achieved this using a combination of [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392795/173113) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493075/173113).

The problem is that this negatively interferes with these commands in a separate environment (`sidebox`, created using `tcolorbox`) I've defined, and overrules specific `hypersetup`-settings defined for that environment. As the name suggests, I'm using this environment as a sort of sidebar/box, in which I'd like all the text (including citations) to be another color.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\xpretocmd{\citeauthor}{\hypersetup{citecolor=black}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citeyear}{\hypersetup{citecolor=black}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citep}{\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citet}{\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}}{}{}

\newcounter{sidebox}
\newenvironment{sidebox}[1]{
\def\sideboxtext{Box}
\hypersetup{citecolor=red}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=sidebox]{sideboxinner}{%
    empty,title={#1},
    minipage boxed title,
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay={}},
    enlarge left by=8mm,
    width=\textwidth-8mm,
    coltitle=red,coltext=red,fonttitle=,fontupper=\hypersetup{linkcolor=red,citecolor=red}\small,fontlower=\hypersetup{linkcolor=red,citecolor=red},
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=2.5mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt 
    }
\begin{sideboxinner}
    }
    {
\end{sideboxinner}}

\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@article{myref,
    title = {Fancy title},
    journal = {Journal of Fancy Publications},
    author = {Jane Dee and John Doe},
    year = {2017},
    pages = {293--311},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\citep{myref}. \citet{myref} was published in the text-coloured year of \citeyear{myref}.

\begin{sidebox}{This is a sidebox}
The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\citep{myref}. \citet{myref} was published in the text-coloured year of \citeyear{myref}.
\end{sidebox}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

This compiles to the following, in which the citations in the sidebox are blue and black.
[image]

Removing the `xpretocmd`-lines yields this, in which the sidebox is formatted as I want it, but `citeauthor` and `citeyear` in the regular text are blue -- rather than black.
[image]

### Attempts so far

Before coming here, I've made a few attempts to solve this on my own. As I reckon the `xpretocmd`-commands affect **all** `citep`-, `citet`-, `citeauthor`- and `citeyear`-commands, I've tried to redefine these conditionally, based on the environment (using `\@currenvir`, which is `tcb@savebox` for the sidebox, by the way). That doesn't work, presumably because these commands are executed in the preamble -- where the environment of use is still unknown.

I've also tried to redefine these `xpretocmd`-commands at the start of the `sidebox`-code (where I also change the `hyperref`-settinsg) and reset them at the end, without success.

### Question

My question is fairly straightforward: how can I achieve the desired situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer by @coffeetable, I've found the solution below. This is slightly different (rather than defining the colors in the `sideboxinner`-part, I do so higher up), in order not to indent the first line of the sidebox-content. Adding `%`-signs and/or removing linebreaks (based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines) thread) didn't solve that problem.

In any case, this removes the need for the additional `hypersetup`-command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\colorlet{citeauthor}{black}
\colorlet{citeyear}{black}
\colorlet{citep}{blue}
\colorlet{citet}{blue}

\xpretocmd{\citeauthor}{\hypersetup{citecolor=citeauthor}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citeyear}{\hypersetup{citecolor=citeyear}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citep}{\hypersetup{citecolor=citep}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citet}{\hypersetup{citecolor=citet}}{}{}

\newcounter{sidebox}
\newenvironment{sidebox}[1]{
\def\sideboxtext{Box}
\colorlet{citeauthor}{red}
\colorlet{citeyear}{red}
\colorlet{citep}{red}
\colorlet{citet}{red}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=sidebox]{sideboxinner}{%
    empty,title={#1},
    minipage boxed title,
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay={}},
    enlarge left by=8mm,
    width=\textwidth-8mm,
    coltitle=red,coltext=red,fonttitle=,fontupper=\small,fontlower=,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=2.5mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt 
    }
\begin{sideboxinner}
    }
    {
\end{sideboxinner}}

\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@article{myref,
    title = {Fancy title},
    journal = {Journal of Fancy Publications},
    author = {Jane Dee and John Doe},
    year = {2017},
    pages = {293--311},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\citep{myref}. \citet{myref} was published in the text-coloured year of \citeyear{myref}.

\begin{sidebox}{This is a sidebox}
The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\citep{myref}. \citet{myref} was published in the text-coloured year of \citeyear{myref}.
\end{sidebox}

The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\citep{myref}. \citet{myref} was published in the text-coloured year of \citeyear{myref}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not change hypersetup, but define new color which can be changed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\colorlet{citeauthor}{black}
\colorlet{citeyear}{black}
\colorlet{citep}{blue}
\colorlet{citet}{blue}

\xpretocmd{\citeauthor}{\hypersetup{citecolor=citeauthor}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citeyear}{\hypersetup{citecolor=citeyear}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citep}{\hypersetup{citecolor=citep}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citet}{\hypersetup{citecolor=citet}}{}{}

\newcounter{sidebox}
\newenvironment{sidebox}[1]{
\def\sideboxtext{Box}
\hypersetup{citecolor=red}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=sidebox]{sideboxinner}{%
    empty,title={#1},
    minipage boxed title,
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay={}},
    enlarge left by=8mm,
    width=\textwidth-8mm,
    coltitle=red,coltext=red,fonttitle=,fontupper=\small,fontlower=,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=2.5mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt 
    }
\begin{sideboxinner}
\colorlet{citeauthor}{red}
\colorlet{citeyear}{red}
\colorlet{citep}{red}
\colorlet{citet}{red}
    }
    {
\end{sideboxinner}}

\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@article{myref,
    title = {Fancy title},
    journal = {Journal of Fancy Publications},
    author = {Jane Dee and John Doe},
    year = {2017},
    pages = {293--311},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\citep{myref}. \citet{myref} was published in the text-coloured year of \citeyear{myref}.

\begin{sidebox}{This is a sidebox}
The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\citep{myref}. \citet{myref} was published in the text-coloured year of \citeyear{myref}.
\end{sidebox}

The work by \citeauthor{myref} was a fancy read~\citep{myref}. \citet{myref} was published in the text-coloured year of \citeyear{myref}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

[image]